# Possible to automate Excel running on desktop from web app?

Tags: excel, web, vb6, automation

We are upgrading a VB6 desktop app and I am investigating the possibility of converting it to a web app.  However one of the main features of this app is that it automates Excel from the VB6 code; see [Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt80be78.aspx)

Therefore, is it possible for a web app, either from server-side code (running on web server) and/or client-side code (running in web browser), to control an Excel executable running on the client's desktop?

The code will need to call on the Excel executable to manipulate Excel workbooks, set visibility of worksheets, unprotect worksheets, clear contents from ranges, as the user (an accountant) interacts with the web app **and** Excel.

ActiveX might be out of the question due to security reasons (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752035(v=vs.85).aspx) although it is an intranet app.

If this is not possible, are there alternative ideas to achieve similar results?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my **Windows** development experience, my suggestion would be to create a **.net dll** that will serve as an intermediary between the **browser** and **Excel**.  This dll would host an **embedded http** or **websocket** server, depending upon whether your use case would be better served by utilizing the **stateless request/response model** or the **persistent connection** provided by a **websocket**.  The embedded server would then be callable from your web application **JavaScript** through the provided **xmlhttp** functionality or an **HTML5 websocket** respectively.  The .net dll would also provide the interface to Excel through .net's **interop** mechanism.  Some issues to consider with these options are:

- **Security** - Windows requires that specific **permissions** be granted to the user/group to start up an http based listener
- **How does the server get launched?** - you could have a **html link** to an excel document on a page of your web app that invokes your .net *executable* when loaded (there may be security issues to contend with here also).  You could also incorporate your .net *assembly* into a Windows **service** project and configure the resulting application to start automatically via the **Windows Service Control Manager**.

Some links to get you started:

- **.net Embedded WebSockets Server**

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server
  - https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp
- **.net Embedded Http Server**

  - https://github.com/Code-Sharp/uHttpSharp
- **.net Interop**

  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx
- **Creating a Windows Service Application**

  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx

I hope this helps.

Comment: How would the JavaScript address the embedded server running on the workstation:  localhost:<pre-agreed port number>?  While I appreciate this OOTB thinking, a service needs to be pre-installed on each user's (accountant's) workstation which could onerous, but could be rolled out by workstation management software.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Localhost and a pre-agreed port and uri on which the embedded server would be configured to listen.  If a service is not ideal, I think it should also be possible to create an **Excel Add In** from the **.net assembly** that could load on start up of the Excel application and launch the embedded server.